# How to calculate Moving Average (the average of n previous elements of an array) in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, moving-average

`PHP` has the function of `trader_sma` for calculating the moving average. Since the concept is simple, I tried to write a function to do so. For this purpose, I kept the last `n` elements in an array during a loop, as

```
function sma($array,$period){
    foreach($array as $element){
        $c[$element[0]]=$element[1];
            if(count($c)>$period){
                $garbage = array_shift($c);
                $average = array_sum($c)/$period;
                $result[]=array($element[0],$average);
            }
    }
return($result);
}
```

where the input and output arrays have the structure of `array(array(['x'],['y']))`

The function works perfectly, but when having large inputs, the PHP `trader_sma` is 10 times faster than my function. Therefore, I came to the conclusion that my function is not the correct or at least the efficiency way.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `trader_sma` is written in compiled C and your PHP is an interpreted script.

Comment: You don't have to compute the sum for every iteration. Simply multiply by N, subtract the oldest value, add the newest value, and divide by N again.

Comment: @Peter very good trick indeed.

Comment: @AbraCadaver you're right, but I didn't except such a huge difference, particularly because of massive improvement in the performance of latest versions of PHP.